# Incorrect date (0000-00-00 00:00:00) when convert android sms database date

Tags: php, android, sqlite, http-post, android-contentresolver

I am new in android.
I have an android program that sent user's sms data from android database to mysql database with `httpPost` request and using `PHP` at server side.

I test it on three devices a `Sony j` with android 4+, a `Samsung Galaxy` with android 4+ and a `LG` device.

In mysql database SMSes from `Sony` and `Samsung` are true and without any errors but smses from `LG` have a big error that date of all is `0000-00-00 00:00:00` in my mysql database.

code of android side :

```
indexID = cursor.getColumnIndex("_id");
indexAddress = cursor.getColumnIndex("address");
indexBody = cursor.getColumnIndex("body");
indexDate = cursor.getColumnIndex("date");
indexRead = cursor.getColumnIndex("read");
indexStatus = cursor.getColumnIndex("status");
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        if (Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(indexRead)) < 1) {
    read = false;
            }
            else {
                read = true;
            }
            switch (Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(indexStatus))) {
            case -1:
                status = MessageStatus.None;
                break;
            case 0:
                status = MessageStatus.Completed;
                break;
            case 32:
                status = MessageStatus.Pending;
                break;
            default:
                status = MessageStatus.Faild;
                break;
            }
            long id = cursor.getLong(indexID);

                smses.add(new SMSMessage(id,    cursor.getString(indexAddress).replaceAll("-", ""),
                        cursor.getString(indexBody), new Date(cursor.getLong(indexDate)),
                        type, read, status));
```

send data from android :

```
SimpleDateFormat mySQLFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(serverAddress);
        String sendStr = "";
        int j = 0;
        try {
            for(int i = 0; i < smses.size() && j < 20; i++) {           
                if(smses.get(i) == null || smses.get(i).ID <= maxId)
                    continue;
                j++;
                sendStr += smses.get(i).getAddress() + "`first`";
                sendStr += smses.get(i).getBody() + "`first`";
                sendStr += mySQLFormat.format(smses.get(i).getDate()) + "`first`";
                sendStr += Integer.toString(smses.get(i).getType().ordinal()) + "`first`";
                if (smses.get(i).isRead()) {
                sendStr +=  "1" + "`first`";
                }
                else {
                    sendStr += "0" + "`first`";
                }
                sendStr += Integer.toString(smses.get(i).getStatus().ordinal()) + "`second`";

                MAXID = smses.get(i).ID;

            }

            ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("syncType", "smstocount"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userID", userID));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data", sendStr));

            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, "UTF-8"));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

PHP side :

```
function smsSyncToCount()
{
global $serverAddress, $DBusername, $DBpassword, $DBname;
$userID = $_POST['userID'];
$data   = $_POST['data'];
$smses = explode('`second`', $data);

$con = mysql_connect($serverAddress, $DBusername, $DBpassword);
if (!$con)
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    return false;
}
mysql_select_db($DBname, $con);mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
foreach($smses as $item)
{
    list($number, $text, $date, $type, $read, $status) = explode("`first`", $item);

    $counter = 0;

    if(!isset($number) || trim($number)==='')
        continue;

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `r_sms` WHERE `user_id` = '".$userID."' AND `number` = '".$number."' AND `date` = '".$date."' AND `type` = '".$type."'");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $counter++;
    }
    if ($counter < 1)
    {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO `r_sms` (`user_id`, `number`, `text`, `date`, `type`, `read`, `status`) VALUES ('".$userID."', '".$number."', '".$text."', '".$date."', '".$type."', '".$read."', '".$status."')") or die (mysql_error());
    }

}
mysql_close($con);
echo 'ok sent';
return true;
}
```

I can't understand bug and why in `LG` devices date is NULL ???

Comment: did you output the LG date values as a string? MySQL gives you the all-zeroes date value if whatever you tried to stuff in could not be interpreted as a date. For mysql, that means it has to be in the `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` format. Anything else is likely to get zeroed out.

Comment: that device is not in my hand and he is a test user. but date column in `mysql` declared in `varchar` type.

Comment: if it's varchar, then there's absolutely no way mysql would convert ANY string to all-zeroes like that. In any case, your code is vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: It is a test, So error is in my code or device?

Comment: basic debugging: `var_dump($_POST)` and see what php's receiving. if everything's ok there, then it's a php problem. if it's bad, then it's a sender problem